# How to make a percentage button work in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Edit**

**Was able to make it work, but now when I click Tax button it says that result is NaN. How do I fix it?**

Have a small calculating app build in react-native. All buttons work except the Tax one. For the Tax button, I need it to add 12% to the result of either addition, subtraction, multiplication or division of two numbers. Can someone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong here? Tried looking online, but wasn't able to find the solution. Would be very glad if someone will point to the mistake.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class Counter extends React.Component {

state = {
    num: 0,
}

inp1 = 0;
inp2 = 0;

handleSubtract = () => {
    this.setState({
        num:this.inp1-this.inp2
    })
}

handleAdd = () => {
    this.setState({
        num: this.inp1 + this.inp2
    })
}

handleDivide = () => {
    this.setState({
        num: this.inp1 / this.inp2
    })
}

handleMultiply = () => {
    this.setState({
        num: this.inp1 * this.inp2
    })
}

handleTax = () => {

    var newNum = this.num / 100 * 12;

    this.setState({
        num: newNum
    })
}

handleNum1 = (text) => {
    this.inp1 = parseInt(text);
}

handleNum2 = (text) => {
    this.inp2 = parseInt(text);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.flexBox}>
            <Text style={styles.flexTitle}>Hi, welcome to my app!</Text>
            <View style={styles.inpBox}>
                <TextInput
                    style={[styles.inps, {marginRight: 10}]}
                    placeholder="Num1"
                    keyboardType="phone-pad"
                    onChangeText={this.handleNum1}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inps}
                    placeholder="Num2"
                    keyboardType="phone-pad"
                    onChangeText={this.handleNum2}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.butBox}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.handleSubtract}
                        title="Subtract"
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.handleAdd}
                        title="Add"
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.handleMultiply}
                        title="Multiply"
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.handleDivide}
                        title="Divide"
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.button, {height: 65, width: 65}]}>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.handleTax}
                        title="Tax"
                        color="#f00"
                />
                </View>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.numBox}>
                {this.state.num}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
flexBox: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
},

flexTitle: {
    padding: 10,
},

inpBox: {
    flexDirection: "row",
},

inps: {
    width: "20%",
    height: 50,
    textAlign: "center",
},

butBox: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
},

button: {
    width: "20%",
    height: 50,
},

numBox: {
    padding: 20,
    fontSize: 32,
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one mistake on your code to make it work the way you want it.
In your function `handleTax`

You are referring to the wrong `num`.

Instead of `this.num` refer to it like this - `this.state.num`

will look like below:

```
handleTax = () => {
    var newNum = this.state.num / 100 * 12;

    this.setState({
        num: newNum
    });
}
```

This will get rid of the NaN result.

To get your proper tax calculation is like below:

`var newNum = this.state.num + this.state.num * 0.12;`

[image: SCREENSHOT SAMPLE]

Answer (score 1):

hi i think i will help you.
whenever click the Tax button so display calculation of percentage right ?
i have calculate the percentage and display to click tax button .

```
   import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class Counter extends React.Component {

    state = {
        num: 0
    }

    inp1 = 0;
    inp2 = 0;
    inp3 = 12;


    handleSubtract = () => {
        this.setState({
            num:this.inp1-this.inp2
        })
    }

    handleAdd = () => {
        this.setState({
            num: this.inp1 + this.inp2
        })
    }

    handleDivide = () => {
        this.setState({
            num: this.inp1 / this.inp2
        })
    }

    handleMultiply = () => {
        this.setState({
            num: this.inp1 * this.inp2
        })
    }

    handleTax = () => {
        let calculation = parseInt(this.state.num) * parseFloat(this.inp3) / 100
        this.setState({
            num: this.state.num - parseFloat(calculation)

        })
    }

    handleNum1 = (text) => {
        this.inp1 = parseInt(text);
    }

    handleNum2 = (text) => {
        this.inp2 = parseInt(text);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.flexBox}>
                <Text style={styles.flexTitle}>Hi, welcome to my app!</Text>
                <View style={styles.inpBox}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={[styles.inps, {marginRight: 10}]}
                        placeholder="Num1"
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                        onChangeText={this.handleNum1}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inps}
                        placeholder="Num2"
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                        onChangeText={this.handleNum2}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.butBox}>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={this.handleSubtract}
                            title="Subtract"
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={this.handleAdd}
                            title="Add"
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={this.handleMultiply}
                            title="Multiply"
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={this.handleDivide}
                            title="Divide"
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={[styles.button, {width: "30%", height: 60}]}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={this.handleTax}
                            title="Tax"
                            color="#f00"
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.numBox}>
                    {this.state.num}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    flexBox: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },

    flexTitle: {
        padding: 10,
    },

    inpBox: {
        flexDirection: "row",
    },

    inps: {
        width: "20%",
        height: 50,
        textAlign: "center",
    },

    butBox: {
        margin: 5,
        flexDirection: "row",
        width: "100%",
    },

    button: {
        width: "15%",
        height: 50,
    },

    numBox: {
        padding: 20,
        fontSize: 32,
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes. When you click a Tax button it must add 12% to the sum and show the result of it. Tried your method, still shows NaN error

Comment: i am using above code and i was getting a successfully result

Comment: Tried with the full code, still gives me an error of NaN.

Comment: Please tell me what is your scenario.
My scenario is first input 20 and second input 20 Then click add button so i will get  40 and then click on tax button and i will get 32.2

Comment: I enter 10 and multiply it by 10 and got 100 and when I click Tax the result is NaN. Same with any other functions.

Comment: r u working on android device right ? 
so reinstall applications and this error is created in handleTax function so check carefully this function.

 handleTax = () => {
        let calculation = parseInt(this.state.num) * parseFloat(this.inp3) / 100
        this.setState({
            num: this.state.num - parseFloat(calculation)

        })
    }

Comment: No, I'm using iOS

Comment: are you define anywhere in string ?
and also You can check with the Conditions the getting values isNan or not.
in which type you are get the value in INT,Float or string. 
also check with typeof .

Comment: What do you mean by define in string?

Comment: check isnan condition and alert or console.log to see what is the result u r getting
 if (isnan(variable)) {
        // handle nan here
    }
    else {

    }

Comment: Can you please explain to me what do you mean by num: this.state.num - parseFloat(calculation)? Why are we subtracting? When I use your code and do 10*10+12% I'm getting 88 instead of 112.

Comment: you will get the 12% of the value right ?
so i am calculate 10*10 = 100 right 
and then calculate 12% of the 100
so Calculation is 100 *12 / 100 = 12
so tax is 12 right the tax is subtract from the values 
so, 100 - 12 = 88

Comment: and what you will get the results depends on calculate right
 you can subtract the tax of the value so u can get 88
and you can add the tax of the value so u can get 112

Comment: I need the Tax button to show the total amount with Tax all together

Comment: okay then calculate below code 
not subtract 
use add  
 handleTax = () => {
        let calculation = parseInt(this.state.num) * parseFloat(this.inp3) / 100
        this.setState({
            num: this.state.num + parseFloat(calculation)

        })
    }